# Call Function only single time for multiple places in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT
    dbo.TotalPackagedQty(t1.int_PackingListDetailId),
    float_Quantity,
    int_PackingListDetailId
        CASE
            WHEN dbo.TotalPackagedQty(t1.int_PackingListDetailId) = 0 THEN 1
            WHEN dbo.TotalPackagedQty(t1.int_PackingListDetailId) < float_Quantity THEN 2
            WHEN dbo.TotalPackagedQty(t1.int_PackingListDetailId) = float_Quantity THEN 3
        END
FROM tblSdPackingListDetail t1
WHERE int_PackingId = '10901032014121313496PM0'
```

This is a sql query.

I am using a function with the name dbo.TotalPackagedQty(t1.int_PackingListDetailId).

I am using this function 4 times in query. Output is coming correct, but i want to call this function only single time to increase speed of the query.

Kindly suggest me a better option in query not stored procedure or other things.

Comment: Also, *if* `TotalPackagedQty` is a deterministic function and you've got a decent optimizer, it should already be calling the function only once per row, even though the function appears *textually* in the query multiple times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
    value,
    float_Quantity,
    int_PackingListDetailId =
                CASE
                    WHEN value = 0 THEN 1
                    WHEN value < float_Quantity THEN 2
                    WHEN value = float_Quantity THEN 3
                END
FROM dbo.tblSdPackingListDetail t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT value = dbo.TotalPackagedQty(t1.int_PackingListDetailId)
) tt
WHERE int_PackingId = '10901032014121313496PM0'
```

Answer (score -2):

Declare variable and try it

```
DECLARE @totalPackagedQty int;
set @totalPackagedQty=dbo.TotalPackagedQty(t1.int_PackingListDetailId);
```

Then use `totalPackagedQty` at all the places instead of function call.

Comment: You can't use `t1.` this way.

Comment: @ypercube, yes it's an alias. Thanks for noticed to me.